# Good Reference For Design And implementation Of Proof-Assistant

Tags: reference-request, proof-assistants

Hello I'm searching for any good review article or book about the design an implementation of a proof-assistant, something such as the Dragon book for programming language. My background is undergraduate in maths.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This would be a start: https://www.andres-loeh.de/LambdaPi/

Comment: There isn't one, alas; I would recommend John Harrison's _Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning_ for a gentle introduction.